# Sublime - expand selection only to matches

Tags: linux, sublimetext3, gnome

Sublime-Text-3 Expands the selection in a weird manner.I have the following Code-Snippet:

```
    appName = "Weired Application"
    for i in appName:
        print i
```

When i select *i* and want to expand selection to the next occurrence, it will select the *i* of the word *in*. How can i expand selections only to matches? When i mark "i" it will show the correct selection, which is the *i* next to print but its expanding to the next occurring character.

I already tried almost every combination in search/replace (as those options are related to CTRL + D as well)

Comment: Without using a regex, you could always select `i` + the adjacent whitespace and then "Quick Add Next" - `super` + `D`

Comment: super == alt? alt + D doesnt work, did you mean Ctrl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried to just place the cursor next to i then CTRL + D? in my case(Windows 8.1), selecting a block on i then CTRL + D and placing cursor before/next to i then CTRL + D gave me different outcome, and placing cursor(not making a block) gave me the result that you wanted.

Comment: absolutely! thats true.